# Is it possible to display a php content with an ajax event?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Sorry it is quite hard for me to ask the correct question, as I do not really know what I am doing...
I have a form, where I include a php that is per default creating 3 different lines:

```
<form method="GET" name="NeuerLieferschein" action="Teileposten_INSERT.php">
<?PHP
    include ("NeuerLieferschein_Teilespalten.php");
?>
```

--> `NeuerLieferschein_Teilespalten.php` contains this loop that creates in the beginning
3 different lines with different fields called `kunde1`, `kunde2`, `kunde3`:

```
<?PHP
    if(isset($_POST['von']))
        {
        $von=trim($_POST['von']);
        $bis=$von;
        }
    else 
        {
        $von=1;
        $bis=3;
        }
for($i=$von; $i < ($bis+1); $i++)
    {
        require_once("DBFunctions.php");
        DBConnect();
        $sql="SELECT distinct Nachname, ';' FROM Kunde order by Nachname asc";
        $db->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_NUM);
        $Nachnamen=$db->Execute($sql);  
        echo '<select name="kunde'.$i.'" id="kunde'.$i.'" class="kunde'.$i.'" onclick="selectkunde('.$i.')" >';
        echo'<option selected="selected"> </option>';
        while (!$Nachnamen->EOF)
            {
            $Nachnamenzeile=($Nachnamen->fields);
            echo'<option value='.$Nachnamenzeile[0].'>'.$Nachnamenzeile[0].'</option>';
            $Nachnamen->MoveNext();
            }

        echo '</select> <br/>';
        DBClose();
```

This works fine.
Now I want to have a new line created with an option id `kunde4` if a button is clicked.
And then a fith line with option `kunde5` if somthing is clicked.

I added the following to the html page:

```
<div id="VariableZeilen" name="VariableZeilen" class="VariableZeilen">
    <p id="VariableZeilen" name="VariableZeilen" class="VariableZeilen">
    <!-- ADD NEW LINES HERE -->
    </p>
    </div>
    <tr>
    <td colspan=3>Zeilen erweitern auf<input id="clicked" size="4" onfocus="this.blur();" onclick="mehrTeile();" value="4">
```

And this as Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var clickCount = 4;
function documentClick()
{
    document.getElementById('clicked').value = ++clickCount;
    return clickCount
}
document.onclick = documentClick;
function mehrTeile()
{
var von=document.getElementById('clicked').value;

var dataString = 'von='+ von;
alert ( ( dataString ) );
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "NeuerLieferschein_Teilespalten.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
complete: function (html) {
        //I get this alert, so I come so far:
        alert("ajax completed ");
        //This should show the output in the html section but nothing happens
    $(".VariableZeilen").html(html); 

      }
});
return false;  
}
</script>
```

Now I can see that with the alert the dataString is counting up every time I click. But what I am not able to, is to Show the php content of the `NeuerLieferschein_Teilespalten.php` in my `<p id=VariableZeilen>`

I am very new to Javascript so I guess it might be a very stupid question, but my searches in forums just didn't lead me to the right answers. I am very happy if someone can help me to code this for dummies. Thanks /Eve

Comment: Your `div` and `p` both have `id="VariableZeilen"`, why? `$(".VariableZeilen")` addresses all elements that have `class="VariableZeilen"` for the id you have to use `#`

Comment: (and this is why everybody uses english in their code :(. Sorry but, I just can't guess what it is, even with all your explanations). But I think you don't need AJaX, just a little dom manipulation

Comment: Short answer: **yes, it's possible.** The long answer is a bit involved. Simply put, without knowledge of your framework (which looks custom made), at first glance, your issue seems to be related to how requests are made and executed.

Comment: are you sure that your complete: function(html) contains anything?

Comment: OK I have changed it to <p id="VariableZeilen1" name="VariableZeilen1" class="VariableZeilen1">
 <!-- Hier weitere Zeilen erzeugen wenn nötig -->
 </p> and I have changed the javascript to $("#VariableZeilen1").html(html); --> But it is still nothing happening. I am wondering if it is at all possible to display the whole php echo's in the p section there?

Comment: I am writing a long answer just now, may take some minutes ;)

Comment: I am not using a framework, it is just a self created mysql database and php code. But to make it more dynamical I do now need to add javascript/ajax.

Comment: @Jim: No I am not sure. If I display it in an alert it displays object.object. How can I test this? But when I run the php itself it contains the first 3 rows of my form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `NeuerLieferschein_Teilespalten.php` is working correct I would suggest some changes. You have an input field, however no matter the value there will always only be one field added due to your PHP script.

This is why I would change

```
Zeilen erweitern auf<input id="clicked" size="4" onfocus="this.blur();" onclick="mehrTeile();" value="4">
```

To something like the following

```
<input type="button" value="Eine Zeile hinzuf&uuml;gen" onclick="mehrTeile();" />
```

Now that you don't have an input field but only a button, you can just use the JavaScript variable for keeping track of the number of the field.

```
function mehrTeile()
{
    var dataString = 'von=' + clickCount; // we will increase clickCount later
```

Now to the main part of your script, the ajax. Instead of `complete` you need to use `success`, also if you use `.html()` you will always replace the content you loaded before. Meaning if you change it once and want to change it again, at the moment it won't keep the changes. Since you only add one row at a time that makes no sense, so `.append()` would be more wise.

All this would lead to the following

```
<form method="GET" name="NeuerLieferschein" action="Teileposten_INSERT.php">
<?PHP
    include ("NeuerLieferschein_Teilespalten.php");
?>
<p id="VariableZeilen"></p>
<input type="button" value="Eine Zeile hinzuf&uuml;gen" onclick="mehrTeile();" />
```

And this JavaScript

```
var clickCount = 4;
function mehrTeile()
{
    var dataString = "von="+clickCount;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "NeuerLieferschein_Teilespalten.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("div#VariableZeilen").append(msg);
            clickCount++;
        }
    });
}
```

I would also suggest to edit the `NeuerLieferschein_Teilespalten.php` a bit. `name="kunde'.$i.'"` means that in the end you will have an unknown amount of fields and can't check it smooth. If you use `name="kunde[]"`, you will get an array of all elements.

```
name="kunde'.$i.'"
-> $_POST['kunde1'] = ?
   $_POST['kunde2'] = ?
   $_POST['kunde3'] = ?
   $_POST['kunde4'] = ?

name="kunde[]"
-> $_POST['kunde'] = array(
   ?,
   ?,
   ?,
   ?,
)
```

Where `?` simply leaves any value open

Comment: Hi kingkero, thanks for your help. I changed the code and the counting ++ really works much better then before! Thanks for teaching me this smooth way of coding it! Now I am still not able to display the new line, even though I have changed the div/p section having only this id to:  

    <div>
     <p id="VariableZeilen"></p>
     </div>

                                                               and I have changed the javascript to

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var clickCount = 4;
    function mehrTeile()
    {
     var dataString = "von="+clickCount;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "NeuerLieferschein_Teilespalten.php",
            data: dataString,      
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $("div#VariableZeilen").append(msg);
       alert(clickCount);
                clickCount++;
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

Comment: --> it is alerting but it is not showing the output of the php code. I have not yet changed the $_POST[] even though I understand it is a very good idea, but I need to go step by step. I have changed the php to a get method, just to be able to call it on the browser and see if it is displaying the right things. So if I call it like this: http://www.auto-christes.de/Buero/NeuerLieferschein_Teilespalten.php?von=4 --> it is displaying a line as expected. So what am I doing wrong???

Comment: sorry that I am writing comments, but as I am new I am not allowed to answer my questions today.

Comment: You are requesting `GET` with your ajax but checking for `POST` in your PHP?

Comment: No I have changed the PHP to GET method as well, in order to being able to test if NeuerLieferschein_Teilespalten.php?von=4 gives the correct line.

Comment: Please edit your question then so we can see your current code

Answer (score 0):

After analysing this issue for a long time, I have now discovered, that it works with Mozilla Firefox 20.0.1 but not with Internet Explorer 8.0.6 which is the latest version for the old windows XP machine I am using. 
Is there anything I can do to make this code also working with IE8?
Is it about my table structure in PHP and HTML or is it about the response itself?

This is where my div is in the table:

```
<tr>
<td colspan=5>
<div id="VariableZeilen" class="VariableZeilen">
<!-- More Lines should appear here --> 
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

And the php is adding more table structure like this:

```
for($i=$von; $i < ($bis+1); $i++)
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th rowspan="2" align=left>Bezeichnung: <input type="text" ';
echo 'name="Teileposition'.$i.'" id="Teileposition'.$i.'" size="50"></th>';
echo '<th rowspan="2"> Nettopreis: <input type="text" onblur="Calculatenettobrutto('.$i.');"';
echo 'name="Netto'.$i.'" id="Netto'.$i.'" size="3"></th>';
echo '<th rowspan="2">Brutto: <input type="text" ';
echo 'name="Brutto'.$i.'" size="3" id="Brutto'.$i.'"/></th>';
echo '<td>';
//Jetzt den Nachnamen auswählen
require_once("DBFunctions.php");
DBConnect();
$sql="SELECT distinct Nachname, ';' FROM Kunde order by Nachname asc";
$db->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_NUM);
$Nachnamen=$db->Execute($sql);  
echo '<select name="kunde'.$i.'" id="kunde'.$i.'" class="kunde'.$i.'" onclick="selectkunde('.$i.')" >';
echo'<option selected="selected"> </option>';
while (!$Nachnamen->EOF)
    {
    $Nachnamenzeile=($Nachnamen->fields);
    echo'<option value='.$Nachnamenzeile[0].'>'.$Nachnamenzeile[0].'</option>';
    $Nachnamen->MoveNext();
    }

echo '</select> <br/>';
DBClose();


    echo '</td>';
    echo '<th rowspan="2">';
    echo '<select name="Teilezurodnung" id="Teilezurodnung" size="1">';
    echo '<option value="Kunde" selected >Kunde</option>';
    echo '<option value="Lager" >Lager</option>';
    echo '<option value="Zurück" >Zurück</option>';
    echo '<option value="Falsch" >Falsch</option>';

    echo '</th>';
    echo '<tr><td>';
    //Je nach Nachname sollten hier die Autos erscheinen
    echo '<select name="auto'.$i.'" class="auto'.$i.'"><option selected="selected">--Wähle das Auto--</option></select>';
    echo '</td></tr>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Sorry I have found it myself now. When I add an echo '<table> in my loop everything works fine in IE8 as well.